# change SharePoint Online listview behavior spfx customizer

Tags: listview, spfx, spfx-extension

I was trying to find a way to customize the default SharePoint modern listview with the SPFX customizer but it seemed to me you can only add command sets to it.

What I am trying to achieve is that we can disable, all default behavior to change the lists view, and on clicking in an item to open a react form.

I see that it is sort of possible with the pnp listview control:
[article 1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pnp-list-view-control-in-sharepoint-framework/)
[article 2](https://rasper87.wordpress.com/2018/01/05/spfx-react-controls-listview-control/)

But is there any other way to achieve this with SPFX customizer?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

With spfx customizer i think the answer is no. You can add buttons, change fields but your requirements are out of possible options. Suggest to go with mentioned pnp listview or custom list view. Maybe with spfx extension you can override some behaviour but it would be “not very nice” (a.k.a. nasty) solution - with css or jquery hide/remove buttons and maybe with spfx field customizer create new columns and render title with custom open behavior. After that change default view and hide default title ...